# GWT how to store information on google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

In my GWT application, a 'root' user upload a specific text file with data and that data should be available to anyone who have access to the app (using GAE).

What's the classic way to store a data that will be available to all users? I don't want to use any database (objectify!?) since this is a relatively small amount of information and it changes from time to time by root.

I was wondering if there was such static MAP on the 'engine level' (not user's session) that this info can be stored (and if the server is down - no bigi, root will upload again)

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to save to any database, your options are limited.  Consider saving it as a static text file to Google Cloud Services (GCS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three primary options:

1. Add this file to your `/war/` directory and deploy with the app. This is what we typically do with all static files that rarely change (like .css file, images, etc.) This file will be available to all users, whether they are authenticated or not.
2. Add this file to your `/war/WEB-INF/` directory and deploy with the app. This file will be available to your server-side code, so you can read it on the server-side and show to a user. This way you can decide which users can see this file and which users should not have access to it.
3. Upload this file to Google Cloud Storage. You can do it through an app, or you can simply upload it manually to a bucket using a GCS console or [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command-line tool. Then you simply provide a link to your users. The advantage of this option is that you do not have to redeploy your app when a file changes.

The only reason to go with the first two options is to have this file under version control. If you don't need that, I would recommend going with the GCS option.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 don't allow for a user to upload the file.  Option 3 is best.

Comment: The OP used the term "root user". It's possible he means one of developers.